# splitting a string->list to be checked

Tags: python, string, split

I've been lurking for a few weeks, and decided to join in order to be more hands-on with my learning of Python.

What I'm trying to do is take a single string, containing several web addresses, and come up with a list containing all the addresses with a domain name of 2-4 characters. The hypothetical addresses are not all simple.com types, they may contain multiple periods. Here's a sample string that I wish to convert:

```
urlstring = 'albatross.org,boogaloo.boolean.net,zenoparadox.hercules.gr,takeawalkon.the.wildside,fuzzy.logic.it,bronzeandiron.age,areyou.serious'
```

To get the addresses in a list: `list(urlstring.split(','))`. But I can't determine how to discern the length of the domain name and delete it or not based on that length. Is it necessary to split each address string into substrings by `split('.')`? =/

I'm pretty sure that this is somehow answered elsewhere, but I couldn't really find something exactly similar. I apologize for the super noobish question, and promise that my questions will improve in quality as I learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only care about the length of the TLD:

```
[url for url in urlstring.split(',') if 2 <= len(url.split('.')[-2]) <= 4]
```

Comment: Edit: I found the problem with your answer: len(url.split('.')[x]), x should be -1, not -2.

Comment: Instead of using `.split` and grabbing the last item, you can use a limited `.rsplit` so that only two items are produced. Thus, `[url for url in urlstring.split(',') if 2 <= len(url.rsplit('.', 1)[1]) <= 4]`. This will raise an exception if there is no '.' in a "url" at all; the original code will silently accept 'com' and silently reject 'bacon'.

Comment: @Goethe: "foobar.com".split('.')[-2] returns "foobar", which is what I thought the OP wanted...

Comment: @karl-knechtel: Good point about rsplit.  It wasn't clear whether that OP wanted to count the subdomain as part of the length.  I was assuming he only wanted the TLD.

Comment: I just wanted to check the TLD, but with -2 as the index in your slice, it only returns the address with the longest TLD

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to get all the urls that have at least one desired, or length-correct, domain name, you could try the following code:

```
def len_is_valid(url, min_len, max_len):
    return any(map(lambda x: min_len<=len(x)<=max_len,url))

urlstring = 'albatross.org,boogaloo.boolean.net,zenoparadox.hercules.gr,takeawalkon.the.wildside,fuzzy.logic.it,bronzeandiron.age,areyou.serious'

url_list = [url for url in urlstring.split(',')
        if len_is_valid(url.split('.'), 2, 4)]

print url_list
# ['albatross.org', 'boogaloo.boolean.net', 'zenoparadox.hercules.gr',
# 'takeawalkon.the.wildside', 'fuzzy.logic.it', 'bronzeandiron.age']
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know which one would be faster or the better approach but here is one using regex:

```
import re

urls = 'albatross.org,boogaloo.boolean.net,bedei9.paralex.zenoparadox.herc.gr,takeawalkon.the.wildside,fuzzy.logic.it,bronzeandiron.age,areyou.serious,mydom.dom.net,hun.com'
regex = re.compile('''[[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2,4}\.[^\.\,]+''')

url_list = regex.findall(urls)
print(url_list)
```

**Note:** I used re.compile but if you are only parsing it once then you dont have to and you can simply do re.findall(patern, urls) and leave it a one liner (after import re of course):

```
url_list = re.findall('''[[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2,4}\.[^\.\,]+''', urls)
```

I also modified the string you gave to make sure it handled several repeats of `abc.abd.abdcde,bdc...`.

If some regex guru is watching and you think you can do better, please do post it, I would love a faster/more accurate solution :).

Also I would like to know from the python gurus which method is faster in this case and which one would handle larger strings better.

Should I post a question asking that? :)